# Make comint-mode behave more like term-mode

Tags: debugging, term, gud

I am constantly getting frustrated with the GDB `comint-mode` buffer when using GUD.  Somehow my cursor always ends up straying from the bottom of the buffer, and then my input is not interpreted how I would expect.

**Is there a way that I can make comint buffers behave more like `term-mode` so that my keys get sent to the underlying process?**

I realize that I will have to manually allow my debugging keys, but that should be easy because I use the function keys almost exclusively when debugging.

Comment: Would it be enough to rebind the movement keys or are there other ways your cursor might end up straying from the bottom?

Comment: @rekado  It often happens when I scroll up to look at the output of the prior command and then scroll back down.  `term-mode` is really good about forcing all input to be at the prompt.  It also prevents deletion of the prompt, which is something that happens more than I care to admit.  Perhaps a better way to phrase my request is "Can I make a `term-mode` buffer receive `comint` commands?"

Comment: You want `comint` to behave like `term-char-mode`. `term-mode` also has a `term-line-mode`, where line are sent to the process. This is not just a matter of language, actually : you *can* activate `term-char-mode` in a comint buffer. It is probably not a supported way of operating comint, it will not work for everything (for example getting completion candidates from the underlying process this way is messy at best), but maybe it will solve your particular issues, it is worth trying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will help, but [realgud](https://github.com/rocky/emacs-dbgr) doesn't have to use comint (although it *can)*. It also works inside eshell. For use with *gdb*, You have to run "set annotate 1" to get it to track source-code lines, after running "M-x set-track-mode".

realgud is available from Melpa. At some point it will be in GNU Emacs Elpa.